# Get/Set error "An object reference is required for the non-static field ...."

Tags: c#

I get an error message "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property...." for calling Refresh function :

> // Status
>
> ```
>     public static string Status 
>     {
>         get 
>           { 
>               return status; 
>           }
>         set 
>         {
>             status = value;
>             Refresh();
>         } 
>     }
>
>     private void Refresh()
>     {
>         lblStatus.Text = Status.ToString();
>     }
> ```

Comment: Well yes, `Refresh` is not static, therefore it must be called on an object instance.

Comment: you are calling non static method from static...so you are getting error

Comment: @JonB: It's not an exception, it's a compile-time error - and a pretty clear one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply make the **Status** property non-static. Clearly you do not share this property across all the instances of that class. It looks like you are working with a control or a page class and you trying to call other instance methods or properties also.

So this will fix the compilation error.

```
public string Status 
....
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only call static functions from static functions.

It should be like

```
public static string Status 
{
    get 
    { 
       return status; 
    }
    set 
    {
        status = value;
        Refresh();
    } 
}

private static void Refresh()  // Change signature of function
{
    lblStatus.Text = Status.ToString();
}
```

**OR**

Make property Non-static

```
public string Status // Change signature of property 
{
    get 
    { 
       return status; 
    }
    set 
    {
        status = value;
        Refresh();
    } 
}

private void Refresh()
{
    lblStatus.Text = Status.ToString();
}
```

Comment: @Cicada: Made `Refresh Static`

Comment: When I change the function to static, lblStatus will give me the same error.

Comment: @KelvinFixx: Why do you want to make property static? Its a bad practice. Make your property and function both non-static as my second snippet(Edit) does.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bad design, because lblStatus is a control, I guess, so it cannot be static, so the Refresh cannot be static.

Therefore, you should not call Refresh() in a static context anyway...

Comment: I want to refresh the lblStatus when the status is changes.

Comment: Then... you should remove static keyword on the Status property!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad design. You should remove the static from the Status.

What you are trying to do is to set instance value from static Property.

You can only modify static fields/properties from static properties/methods.

If you are insisting that Status must be Static then you have to create another static property/field and update through this field. (THIS IS HOWEVER VERY BAD).

Example:
Assuming Status is defined in class Form1, and there will be only one Form1 Instance

```
    Class Form1
    {
        private static Form1 staticInstance = default(Form1);
        Form1()
            {
            staticInstance  = this;
            }
        public static string Status 
        {
            get 
            { 
            return status; 
            }
            set 
            {
                status = value;
                Refresh();
            } 
        }

        private static void Refresh()  // Change signature of function
        {
            if(staticInstance  != default(Form1)
            staticInstance .lblStatus.Text = Status.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Comment: `(THIS IS HOWEVER VERY BAD).`, can you provide me some links which says this is bad ??

Comment: it was IMHO. Why -> staticInstance is created just to remain Status as static. There is no wrong in instance modification by statics, until it goes as per requirement, and proper safeguards have been used to take care of syncrhonization.

Comment: yeah exactly, coz i was using static properties for one of my membership profiler class. so it does depends upon the requirements. i just wanted to clear that is it really bad or what.

Comment: sorry for being unclear, the opinion was only for this question. If static were really bad, they would not have been in the language specs in the first place.